# How do Ioun stones behave?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, intelligent-magic-items

Are they alive, or do they orbit lifeless? The high AC (24) to grab the stone implies a greater level of dodging than something moving predictably.

I guess they're pretty cheap and thus unlikely to be sentient, but the idea of a mischievous stone orbiting my character sounds interesting.

(We're playing Dnd 5e btw, but I'd be curious to hear rules for other systems if they're not too incompatible)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Is your question specifically about whether *ioun stones* actively dodge people trying to grab them or simply orbit in a fixed pattern?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### They are not alive, but do orbit unpredictably.

Dragon magazine #174's *Bazaar of the Bizarre* article on ioun stones describes that ioun stones orbit seemingly randomly, following an individual's magnetic force lines. They aren't intelligent as such, but sometimes move as if they are.

> By firmly grasping a stone, any character can imprint his personal magnetic aura into the gem's structure. The activated crystal is then tossed lightly into the air, where it orbits the user like a small glowing moon. This orbit is not always elliptical but follows a seemingly random, meandering pathway as it maneuvers along the user's magnetic force lines. A stone alternately sits motionless in midair or dances and weaves about, rarely straying more than 3' from its owner. Sometimes, a stone wanders up to 12' from its user for no apparent reason, but it quickly returns, its obscure "Mission" completes.

It also mentions that they can appear to move based on the bearer's thoughts, to a limited extent:

> Some wizards have observed that if a character is looking intently at something, some *ioun stones* that he possesses wil move toward the object of his scrutiny.

This article was written during the AD&D 2e era of D&D, though its lore can still be applied to D&D 5th edition. There is relatively little 5e-specific lore on ioun stones due to the fewer books published and lack of magazines to cover minute details such as the exact orbit of an ioun stone.